# Where can I find the animation for a' top level transition' as described in the material guidelines?

Tags: android, material-design

The [material guidelines](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#peer-transitions) suggest using a transition animation which is made up of a fade and a scale animation, for top level transitions such as with a bottom navigation bar. You can see the [video of the transition](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1NWCbC7aAXsifhMG32vJQd8Mz1LHSvunb%2Fpeertransitions-bottomnav.mp4) here.

How can I add this animation to my fragment transitions?

Comment: Did you figure this out?